# KnockoutValidation and the conditional required rule

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am trying to use [KnockoutValidation](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation) with conditional statements. See code below:

```
self.transactionType = ko.observable('Option1');

self.ConditionalField = ko.observable().extend({
  required: true, 
  onlyIf: self.transactionType = ="Option2"
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I want to have `ConditionalField` only required if `transactionType` has value `'Option2'`.

What is the best way to use conditional validation with knockout.validation.js?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have solved it.

First of all I made the mistake of declaring the `transactiontype` after I had defined the `conditionalfield`. The end code that works looks like this:

```
self.transactionType = ko.observable("Option1");

self.conditionalField = ko.observable().extend({
  required: {
    onlyIf: function () { 
      return self.transactionType () == "Option2";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Well, it's been said Thomas Edison had 3000 failed attempts before he  invented the first commercially practical incandescent light. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Edison#cite_note-28, but I find your answer to be just as illuminating... thanks & + 1

Comment: Sadly this onlyIf stuff is not documented anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: [onlyIf documentation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Conditional-Validation-with-onlyIf-parameter)

Comment: Really useful. I appreciate you took the time to response your own answer. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed!  Still useful 3 years later!